# Русское название нового общественного явления

Tags: фразеология, лексика

В странах бывшей Чехословакии успешно развивается новая практика после развода, когда дети проживают половину времени с отцом и половину с матерью. Ищу для переводов подходящее выражение, может кто-нибудь подскажет? Для сравнения: по-чешски это называется střídavá výchova, по-словацки striedavá  starostlivosť, что буквально означает переменную или чередующуюся опеку. Спасибо.

Comment: Простите, что сильно переформулировал Ваш вопрос. Надеюсь, что смысла не исказил. Нет?

Comment: Вам как русскому было бы понятно, о чем идет речь, услышав: Я разведенный и у меня сын в переменной опеке?

Comment: Нет, не понятно. В России такого нет.

Comment: И как по-русски правильно выразиться, если ребенок проживает половину времени с отцом и половину с мамой? В чешском языке это выражение появилось в 90-ые годы переосмыслением переменного (электрического) тока: střídavý proud - střídavá výchova.

Comment: @TomášJ. *И как по-русски правильно выразиться, если ребенок проживает половину времени с отцом и половину с мамой?* - Вот так и выражайтесь. Иное скорее всего приведет к ситуационному непониманию и даже полному когнитивному диссонансу. Переводчики в этой ситуации (а она известна по американским фильмам) часто именно так и поступают: на словах не экономят.  Подробнее - см. мой ответ.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - насчет не "исказил". Предлагаемые термины лучше бы оставить в именительном падеже. В таком виде они воспринимаются как нечто в общем понятийном поле  русского языка существующее, а не вновь вводимое. Меня лично это поставило в тупик - пришлось смотреть авторский вариант. При всей его стилистичейчкой шероховатости он был абсолютно понятен по сути. А заодно и уровень коммуникативности автора раскрывал. Тоже важно для общения с теми, у кого русский - не родной.

Comment: @TomášJ. И еще, не по теме. Вам, как переводчику, не будет обидно услышать, что фраза *Вам ... было бы понятно, о чем идет речь, услышав...* содержит грубую грамматическую ошибку? Деепричастный оборот не может относиться к глаголу в безличном предложениях типа "Вам приятно". В *современном* русском языке действующее лицо должно быть (за редкими исключениями) тем же, что и у основного глагола - это одно из отличий деепричастия от английского, например, герундия. Поэтому надо сказать  ***Вам было бы понятно, о чем идет речь, если бы Вы услышали..."***.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий и извините за ошибки. Конечно, перевожу с иностранных языков на свой (чешский), стопроцентное владение двумя языками наверно можно наблюдать лишь в двуязычных семьях. Вопрос задаю потому, что даже русские, проживающие в Центральной Европе и ознакомленные с названным явлением затрудняются его перевести. Согласен, что любое можно перевести объяснением, но рад был услышать предложения собеседников. Язык до Киева доведет.

Comment: @TomášJ я вам и сказал как переводчику, в вашей профессиональной среде такие вещи можно говорить спокойно, не боясь нечаянно задеть. Можете не извиняться. А помочь - всегда рад, но тут, если по теме терминологии, есть большие сомнения, что от такой помощи будет какой-то желаемый результат.

Comment: Культурная разница между западными и восточными славянами не так большая. Я уверен, что тема родительского равноправия скоро также в России появится, и потом обязательно будет и точный термин.

Comment: @TomášJ, я буду только рад если в России что-то "начнется". Но вот только будет ли это в сфере "культурной разницы" - сильно сомневаюсь. Проблема совсем в другой плоскости, социальной и менталитета. В принципиальном нежелании большинства россиян и их власти что-то делать в направлении приобщения к мировым представлениям о правах человека и ребенка. Но это не тема для обсуждения на здешнем ресурсе.Буду рад пообщаться на любом форуме, где такие разговоры "в формате".

Comment: Согласен, что уже выходим за рамки чисто филологической дискуссии, но и у нас само явление и его название появились лишь в 90-ые годы и до сих пор есть много разногласий по этой теме. Всему свое время. Если хотите процесс ускорить, обращайтесь к своим депутатам.

Answer (score 3):

Tomáš, в России нет самого понятия для такой ситуации, поэтому и название подобрать очень сложно. Как ни назови, без пояснений понять будет сложно. Поэтому Ваш вопрос, *было бы понятно... "Я разведенный и у меня сын в переменной опеке?"* не совсем корректен.

Но если уж подбирать что-то интуитивно понятное русскому, то нечто типа ***"ребенок воспитывается поочередно (попеременно) обоими родителями"*** Слово "опека", к сожалению, юридически значимо используется в другом значении - в отношении частично дееспособных лиц (сирот, инвалидов, страдающих умственным расстройством граждан), ***опекаемых* вне семейных отношений**. В остальных случаях лучше использовать "уход" или "воспитание".

А вообще, боюсь, что тут лучше всего на данном этапе объяснять понятийно, не жалея слов. Дело в том, что эта сфера в России и без того перегружена разного рода терминами и условностями. Например, *"опекунство", "попечительство", "патронаж", "усыновление"* - это юридически разные понятия, но ни одно не относится к родителям, осуществляющим **воспитание** *собственных* детей. И без того, как говорят в России, *"Черт ногу сломит"*. Поэтому каждый новый термин обязательно кем-то будет понят неправильно.

Answer (score 1):

совместно-раздельное воспитание. к примеру, мой сын находится 
на совместно-раздельном воспитании

Comment: Воспитание - да. Не опека. Но вот что такое "совместно-раздельное" - это "без стакана" и не поймешь. Надо что-то более прозрачное, "поочередное" было более удачное. Поэтому плюс - условный.

Comment: Кстати, преподаватель университета, где я когда-то учился, предложил очень похожий вариант - совместное воспитание с поочередным проживанием.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил *чередующаяся* или *поочерёдная опека*.

Comment: Опека - не то слово. Вот в чем вся беда. А прилагательное - дело десятое, можно найти подходящее...